# Why are my calculated spans slightly less than my durations? [MS Project]

Tags: ms-project

[image: Picture of problem]

I calculated the span based on my start and finish dates to double check the file.

Why are these two columns not equal? Is there a setting wrong somewhere? Does this mean my end date isn't being accurately calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculated span does not include the time between `3/22/05 5:00 PM` and `3/23/05 8:00 AM` which would be exactly 62 weeks after the task started (`1/14/04 8:00 AM`).

Note: MS Project has been around for a long, long time; it calculates the dates correctly.